# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment when trying to assign a sum to value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in which I am using to sum the inputs of two input fields and assign it to one. My function looks like:

```
function sum(id) {
        nextId = id+2
        console.log($("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val())
        $("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val() += $("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val();

    }
```

And the function from which I call the sum function looks like:

```
function makeSub(subRow) {
        var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
        document.getElementById("id_unit_market_price"+subRow.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex).value = 0
        addRow(true);
        sum(subRow.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)
    }
```

The `console.log($("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val())` prints the actual values of the inputs. But when I try to do `$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val() += $("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val();` I get the error `(index):325 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at sum ((index):325)
    at makeSub ((index):318)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)`
I also tried parsing the values into float but that doesn't work either.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using `.val()` you get the value of the element. if you use `.val("something")` you set the value of the element

Comment: `$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val( THE VALUE GOES HERE ) NOT HERE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to assign a sum to value

And that's the problem.

You can assign a value to a *variable* or a *property*. You can't assign a value to a value.

`12 = 1` just doesn't make sense. And it still doesn't make sense if you replace `12` with the return value of a function.

---

The jQuery `val` function accepts an **argument** if you want to change the value of a form control.

```
jq.val(new_value)
```

Thus:

```
const old_value = $("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val();
const value_to_add = $("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val();
const new_value = old_value + value_to_add;
$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val(new_value)
```

or in one statement:

```
$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val(
    $("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val() +
    $("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val()
)
```

---

Keep in mind that values of form controls are **strings** so you'll probably want to [convert them to **numbers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_2) so `+` will **add** them together instead of **concatenating** them.

```
const old_value = +$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val();
const value_to_add = +$("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val();
const new_value = old_value + value_to_add;
$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val(new_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.val()` method should be passed a parameter in order to change the value.

```
let currentVal = $("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val();
$("#id_unit_market_price"+id).val(currentVal + $("#id_unit_market_price"+nextId).val());
```

A function call on the left side of an assignment doesn't make sense in JavaScript.